# Using a recursive / fixed point / iterative structure in a Neo4j Cypher query

Tags: recursion, neo4j, set, cypher

My Neo4j database contains relationships that may have a special property:

`(a) -[{sustains:true}]-> (b)`

This means that `a` *sustains* `b`: when the last node that sustains `b` is deleted, `b` itself should be deleted. I'm trying to write a Cypher statement that deletes a given node PLUS all nodes that now become unsustained as a result. This may set off a chain reaction, and I don't know how to encode this in Cypher. Is Cypher expressive enough?

In any other language, I could come up with a number of ways to implement this. A recursive algorithm for this would be something like:

```
delete(a) :=
    MATCH (a) -[{sustains:true}]-> (b)
    REMOVE a
    WITH b
    MATCH (aa) -[{sustains:true}]-> (b)
    WHERE count(aa) = 0
    delete(b)
```

Another way to describe the additional set of nodes to delete would be with a *fixed point* function:

```
setOfNodesToDelete(Set) :=
    RETURN Set' ⊆ Set such that for all n ∈ Set'
           there is no (m) -[{sustains:true}]-> (n) with m ∉ Set
```

We would start with the set of all `z` such that `(a) -[{sustains:true}*1..]-> (z)`, then delete `a`, run `setOfNodesToDelete` on the set until it doesn't change anymore, then delete the nodes specified by the set. This requires an unspecified number of iterations.

Any way to accomplish my goal in Cypher?

Comment: Does a node need to be sustained by a node that is immediately adjacent, or can it be sustained by a node > 1 steps away?

Comment: By definition, that would be immediately adjacent. However, the 'sustains' relationship is transitive. So in a way you could say that a node > 1 'sustains' relationships away is also sustaining it.